# how to perform migration in django

Tags: django, django-models, database-migration

my model.py file is

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    book_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    publisher_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%d %s %s %s" % (self.book_id,self.book_name, self.author_name,self.publisher_name)


class Author(models.Model):
    author_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    book=models.ForeignKey(Book)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%d %s %s' % (self.author_id,self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

for "class Book" I already created table in MySQL using `manage.py syncdb`. But I am in the way to update the db with new table named as "Author" i need the procedure for doing the same. Because I am trying to do the latter in the same way but table is not created in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`python syncdb` should not create any changes in the existing table
```

Use south migration concept.run the following command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

will make the changes in models.

Answer (score 2):

`syncdb` should create newly-specified tables; if `Author` is not being created it is because it's not coded in a valid manner. Note that the line

```
age=int
```

results in a syntax error; you should specify an [integer field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#integerfield) this way:

```
age=models.IntegerField()
```

However you're better off having [Django South](http://south.aeracode.org/) taking care of anything you have related to DB migration.